# How to perform clustering based on the edges of a graph?

Tags: python, csv, graph, cluster-computing

I have a CSV with the following,

```
x,y,6
y,z,9
y,p,5
x,p,3
```

here, letters are nodes and numbers are the edges. I drew the graph :

```
Gph = nx.read_edgelist(filepath, delimiter=',', data=[('weight', int)]) 
G.edges(data=True)

edge_labels = dict(((u, v), d['weight']) for u, v, d in Gph.edges(data=True))
pos = nx.random_layout(Gph)
#pos = nx.pydot_layout(Gph)
nx.draw(Gph, pos, with_labels=True) 
nx.draw_networkx_edges(Gph, pos, edge_color='b')

plt.show()
```

how to cluster the nodes based on the edges? so the pairs become element of a cluster. x, y is an element of a the cluster.

Comment: You seem to be interchanging `Gph` and `G`.  Is there more code for this that you aren't showing us or is this just something that came up in transcription?

Comment: @Brien its just Gph... typo.. i updated it now

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `nx.random_layout(Gph)`, one option available to you is to try the [`spring_layout`](http://networkx.lanl.gov/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.layout.spring_layout.html#networkx.drawing.layout.spring_layout) algorithm provided by `networkx`.  You'll need `numpy` installed but this force-directed algorithm will cluster the nodes based on the edge weights.

Here is one example of a call to that algorithm, but you can tweak the parameters as needed.  Replace the random layout line with this one.

```
pos = nx.spring_layout(Gph,scale=20)
```

Comment: I did it with spring_layout. but How can I see the clusters? I want the clusters to be printed by not displayed

Comment: Sorry, I don't know of any way to do this.  The only thing I can think of would be to run this algorithm then look and see which nodes were close together and which ones were far away from each other.